# jQuery page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
<body>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main">

        <div class="page-1">
            <p>Page 1</p>
            <button id="btn-page2">Go to Page 2</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Other Pages --> 
        <div class="page-2">
            <p>Page 2</p>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

I am trying to follow the same principle of JQuery mobile by having all the pages in a single HTML document.

On page load, only the div with class page-1 should be displayed. However on clicking the button with id btn-page2, the second page should be displayed instead of the first one.

I figured I could add an .active-page class on the visible page with a display:block as attribute.

However, I also want to slide the second page from the bottom smoothly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Like i said. I added an active class to show active pages. So on load, page-1 gets the active class. On clicking the btn-page2, page-2 gets the active class and I remove the active class from page-1. I also want to animate this bit where page-2 is slided up smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this blog.

http://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/smooth-page-transition-on-mobile-devices-within-single-html-page/

This demonstrates the way to add slide page effect using css3.

You can use the same concept to have the page slide form bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a css3 class which will slide any page from bottom and add it to the page div based on the button clicked